# Can't sort Google Places ['rating'] data in python library

Tags: python, google-maps, google-places-api

While I was doing different tests I found a problem that I can not sort data by  ['rating].values when I call google.places(). 
For instance if I query data and sort by ['name'], it works perfectly fine.
Example below:

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='key_is_here')
nyc = (40.6971494, -74.2598655)
msk = (55.7535081, 37.6144299)
new_arr = []

params = {
    'query': ['restaurants', 'bakery', 'cafe', 'food'],
    'location': nyc
    'radius': 10000
}


gmapz = gmaps.places(**params)
print sorted(gmapz['results'], key = lambda x : x['name'],reverse = True):
        """ outputs list of dicts """
```

However , I when I use ['raiting'] in lambda key, it says

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Aleshka/Desktop/teszz.py", line 22, in <module>
    print sorted(gmapz['results'],key = lambda x : x['rating'],reverse=True)
  File "/Users/Aleshka/Desktop/teszz.py", line 22, in <lambda>
    print sorted(gmapz['results'],key = lambda x : x['rating'],reverse=True)
KeyError: 'rating'
```

Which means that this key does not exist.
At first I thought it could be the reason that google outputs unicode format, but

```
>>> u'abc' == 'abc'
True
```

I am really confused as well, because before that few days ago I was able to do that in location New York(Manhattan to be exact), however when I did few tests in different places and chose Moscow, Russia it broke. Not sure what went wrong.
I thought it could happen because I reached the query limit, but that's not the case.

Comment: If i do it like 

print gmapz['results'][0]['rating']

it does show the rating of the 1st place. I am even more confused now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible that any one of the results might not have the key 'rating'.
Try to debug it by printing results which do not have the key 'rating'.

```
for res in gmapz['results']:
    if 'rating' not in res.keys():
        print res
```

Now you know which are the results that do not have the any ratings.

Comment: I feel like i did not do enough tests then. that was the case indeed.

Answer (score 0):

With the great help of @Shra1 I fixed the problem with

```
print sorted(gmapz['results'], key = lambda x: ('rating' not in x, `x.get('rating',None)),reverse = True)`
```

Displays first item w/o rating and the rest sorted in descending order.